# how to make output line up (Ex. '12345') in python?

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

i have written a simple number generation function but i want the output to line up horizontally('234567') and not vertically like it currently outputs.

```
import random

def get_num():
    listz = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for x in listz:
        print(random.randrange(1,7))
    

get_num()
```

Comment: you use the keyword only arguments `end` of print which determine is you go to the next line or not, ex: `print(x,end="")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join`:

```py
import random

def get_num():
    print(''.join(str(random.randrange(1, 7)) for _ in range(5)))

get_num() # e.g., 16146
```

In your code, `listz` does not play any roles (other than providing its length, 5). So I replaced it with `for _ in range(5)`.

Comment: I think we dont need to stringify integers here. This also works fine.

Comment: super elegant, I likeeeee

Comment: @DineshPandikona You are totally right! But to me, putting logic and `print` in a single function is just not for my taste. I even wanted to get rid of `print` from the function and put it outside the function call, but I didn't want to make further changes...

Comment: @j1-lee What are you guys talking about? If you remove the `str`, it crashes.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh you are also right! I thought just meant that we can just use `print(random.randrange(1, 7), end='')` in a loop as in his answer, without resorting to `join`. But I might have misunderstood him. To use `join`, it is necessary to use `str` of course.

Comment: @j1-lee Nice One,

Answer (score 1):

It is just that you need to add a parameter in the print function as follows :

```
import random

def get_num(): 
    listz = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    for x in listz: 
        y = random.randrange(1,7)
        print(y,end="")

get_num()
```

The output was :

```
$python3 main.py
53234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randrange as rand

def get_randoms():
    randoms = [rand(1, 7) for _ in range(5)]
    randoms_str = [str(x) for x in randoms]
    return ', '.join(randoms_str)

print(get_randoms())
```

Comment: Aside, I’m not sure why there were so many downvotes on your other answer—which you’ve since deleted—though, generally, answers are more useful when they also include an explanation, so that’s a habit I’d get into (and would be useful here, too). I certainly understand the frustration, as I’ve had two recent answers downvoted without an explanation of why. Also, I mentioned you’d get your reputation back, but be aware that may take a bit; reputation is recalculated once a day. Apologies for posting here; your other answer was deleted right before I submitted this comment.

Comment: I really appreciate you support Jeremy. Hopefully I can answer more difficult questions soon once I have studied more.

Answer (score 1):

Could also print in one go with empty separator:

```
import random

def get_num():
    print(*random.choices(range(1, 7), k=5), sep='')

get_num() # e.g., 16146
```

Comment: thank you! that looks like the cleanest way to do it. each of these five digit numbers corresponds to a word on the eff wordlist for creating diceware passwords. i get that nothing truly replaces a dice roll but using this greatly reduces the tedious nature of creating these type of passwords for every new account